# Why are my mode specific .emacs hooks running for all modes?

Tags: emacs, lisp, hook

I'm running the following code in my .emacs file:

```
(defun load-hooks ()
    (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-hook))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'load-hooks)

(defun my-hook () ... )
```

However, the content in `my-hook` is running on save even when I'm in a different mode. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the LOCAL argument to `add-hook`, which will make sure that the hook only affects the current buffer:

```
(defun load-hooks ()
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-hook nil t))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'load-hooks)

(defun my-hook () ...)
```

Comment: So much better than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that calling `(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-hook)` in `load-hooks` adds the hook to *all* modes. That is, once that function is called, `after-save-hook` is modified for every other buffer as well.

I suspect that your hook would *not* be run unless you open a c file. Try opening some file *without* having opened any c files and see if anything is run. If it isn't it just means that the function that runs for c files modifies the save hook for everything else.

Comment: Bang on - is there anyway I can create a after-save for c-mode only hook?

Comment: I am now testing if the current mode is in c-mode. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tikhon was correct about the 'after-save-hook affecting all modes - I am now relying on a check using the following functions:

```
(defun in-c-mode? ()
  (string= (current-major-mode) "c-mode"))

(defun current-major-mode ()
  (with-current-buffer (current-buffer) major-mode))
```

Comment: There's no need to define two new functions for this. I think `(eq major-mode 'c-mode)` should be a sufficient test. Note that `(with-current-buffer (current-buffer) ...)` is redundant, and is basically equivalent to `(progn ...)`.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that my answer was doubly redundant and I can pass an argument for local hooks.